# Unmanaged DLL project and managed WinForms application in one solution

Tags: c#, .net, c++, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2008 Professional, and I need to create solution with two projects. One project is managed WinForms C# project, second is unmanaged DLL C++ project.

I created them in VS2008 and in unmanaged DLL project I exported simple function which returns some int. In managed WinForms project I imported DLL in a usual way and tried to print returned value in label:

```
[DllImport("DllProj.dll", EntryPoint = "GetSomeInt", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetSomeInt();
```

But when I build solution and run, I get `DllNotFoundException`. I also tried to add an existing item(`DllProj.dll`) to WinForms project, but it only copied that dll from its Debug folder to folder with WinForms project, but not in Debug subfolder, where the compiled project resides. So I am still getting `DllNotFoundException`.

I also tried to add it as a reference, but VS2008 complains that my DLL is not COM or managed object. Is there some way to configure solution in such way that I don't need to manually copy the compiled DLL to Debug subfolder of WinForms project after each build?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add dll copy to post build event.

See `Project properties>Build events>Post build event command line`.

Comment: Ok i am there, i see Post-build event command line. Can you advice me that magic command that will copy it? Sorry but i am doing this first time and never used it before.

Comment: Use simple bat-file syntax. For example, "copy c:\MyProjectSource\mydll.dll c:\MyDestination\"

Comment: @sanjuro, You have to use macros like this ('$(OutDir)') or relative paths to prevent breaking when you move your solution to another directory.

Comment: @sanjuro, also you may use target `Output path` project property

Answer (score 2):

- Copy the compiled dll to WinForms project after each build
- Right click on the dll (which resides in WinForms project), click properties
- Set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer"

Comment: Thansk man, it works, but when i change something in dll project it is not reflected in result in WinForms application. So there is no way to configure it like i imagine? Without need to everytime i change dll to copy it manually?

Comment: @sanjuro, you should add copy script to post build event of project as I said. Post build event runs after each build.

Comment: i know from your previous post, but dont know how that copy script looks like. :)

Comment: @sanjuro, I've added comment :)

Answer (score 2):

DllImport is the right way to consume the unmanaged dll, since the c++ project is unmanaged you cannot add it as referemce in the c# windowsforms application and you have to copy manually or with a postbuild event the c++ dll used by DllImport to the bin folder of your managed app.